# Django request.user modification not happening in test

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I have a view that is changing a field of `request.user`:

```py
def test(request):                  
    request.user.is_provider = False
    request.user.save()
    print(request.user.is_provider)
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Now I am testing the function and I have the following test:

```py
class RoleSwitchTests(TestCase):
    def test_switch_to_customer(self):
        User = get_user_model()
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='test',
            email='test',
            password='test',
            first_name='test',
            last_name='test',
            is_provider=True,
            is_admin=False,
        )
        self.client.login(username='test', password='test')
        response = self.client.post('/test/', follow=True)
        print(user.is_provider)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertFalse(user.is_provider)
```

`self.assertFalse(user.is_provider)` fails here. For some reason, `request.user.is_provider` is `False` in `test`, but in `test_switch_to_customer`, `user.is_provider` is `True`. I know these refer to the same user because they have the same `id`, so why is the modification not being preserved here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [refresh_from_db](http://%20https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.refresh_from_db) to reload the updated user from the database after the post

```
user.refresh_from_db()
```

Answer (score 0):

The view and the test are working on different `User` objects, that both have the same primary key. Hence changes made by the view are not done in the `user` in the test.

You can refetch the `User` object, for example with:

```
class RoleSwitchTests(TestCase):
    def test_switch_to_customer(self):
        User = get_user_model()
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='test',
            email='test',
            password='test',
            first_name='test',
            last_name='test',
            is_provider=True,
            is_admin=False,
        )
        self.client.login(username='test', password='test')
        response = self.client.post('/test/', follow=True)
        user = User.objects.get(pk=user.pk)  # fetch from database
        print(user.is_provider)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertFalse(user.is_provider)
```